# ASP.Net Core 3.1 API JWT validation fails in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Working on a ASP.Net Core 3.1 API I am having trouble with JWT (bearer) token validation in production.

Given this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>  
{  
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})  
.AddJwtBearer(x =>  
{  
    x.Authority = config["JwtOptions:Authority"];
    x.Audience = config["JwtOptions:Audience"];
}
```

all works will in my development environment. However, moving to production, the token is found to be invalid. Kestrel returns a WWW-Authenticate header that says:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

I am at loss for the reason for this difference. The only way to get it working in production seems to alter the settings as below, however, this means sacreficing all security that the JWT should provide...

```
x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  
{
    RequireSignedTokens = false, 
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false, 
    SignatureValidator = delegate(string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
    {
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
        return jwt;
    }, 
};
```

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT

The problem lies with HTTP. When using HTTPS, things work fine. This would seem to be a bug in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, since I'd expect this to work with HTTP as well. Microsoft actually has manual for using a reverse proxy to shield Kestrel from the worlds; using HTTP should be fine in that case.

Comment: What are you using to sign the token ?

Comment: I currently use [auth0](http://www.auth0.com) to sign the token. I would expect the API to retrieve the signature from the issuer automatically. This seems not to happen, but I am unsure how to debug this in order to find out more details.

Comment: Are your app settings for client id / client secret for the domain  you're using for production ? Also, check the bearer token that's created is valid in https://jwt.io/

Comment: Yes the token is valid in jwt.io. The consuming app is a desktop application, so there is no secret or domain. There is really real difference between development and test; only that the test API runs on Linux in a VM. That could be the reason, but don't know how to pinpoint the underlying cause.

Comment: If you are deliberately using non-secure HTTP, you are implicitly saying that you trust the servers and network involved... in which case **authentication/authorization, and therefore JWT, is completely unnecessary**. This feels like an X-Y problem: why are you using JWT over HTTP *at all*?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but even so should it not be technically possible to do? The idea was to have nginx as a reverse proxy, which would provide HTTPS. I thought it would make sense to have kestrel<>nginx traffic be over http, since this is on localhost, then configure HTTPS in nginx. Having nginx there would provide more options like compression etc. This seems also to be sort of recommended by Microsft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/when-to-use-a-reverse-proxy?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1).